# Divide/Multiply certain rows in a DF by other Df with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I got 2 df
The first one with the purchase prices by country and year

| year | purchase | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1999 | 23 | Canada |
| 2000 | 24 | Canada |
| 1999 | 21 | China |
| 2999 | 22 | China |

And other with the selling prices by year

| year | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1999 | 25 |
| 2000 | 27 |

So I want to get a column ratio like this:

| year | purchase | country | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1999 | 23 | Canada | 1.086 |
| 2000 | 24 | Canada | 1.25 |
| 1999 | 21 | China | 1.19 |
| 2999 | 22 | China | 1.22 |

Which is like dividing by the selling price where the years are the same.
I tried something like:

```
np.divide(selling["price"],purchase.Price, where= selling["year"]== purchase["years"])
```

but It was unsuccessful.

I'm trying to do it in just one line of code without creating additional elements.
Since I think that I can solve it by creating another variable running in the years like

```
for years in purchase.years: 
   purchase["ratio"] = np.divide(selling[selling.years].Price,purchase[purchase.years ==  years].Price)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `reindex` and `rdiv`

```
df1['ratio'] = df1['purchase'].rdiv(df2.set_index('year')['price'].reindex(df1['year']).values)
df1
Out[316]: 
   year  purchase country     ratio
0  1999        23  Canada  1.086957
1  2000        24  Canada  1.125000
2  1999        21   China  1.190476
3  2999        22   China       NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You could join both the tables together.

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, 
                      on = ['year'],
                      how = 'left')

merged_df['ratio'] = merged_df['price']/merged_df['purchase']
merged_df.drop('price', axis = 1)
```